# Checking whether the user is scrolling or not and if not then set scroll position to bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, scrollbar

Currently I am working on a chatting site. The chat box updates every 200 milliseconds. When the new message is loaded, the scrollbar needs to position on the bottom. I've done it. The problem is, when the user trying to scroll to the top position, the scrollbar falls to the bottom every 200 milliseconds (Because I've set to load new messages every 200 milliseconds and reposition the scrollbar to the bottom.). So this is the problem. Now I would like to check whether the user is scrolling or already scrolled. If the user already scrolled or scrolling when count comes to play, then the scrollbar will stay where it is. If the user has not scrolled at all nor is he scrolling now, then the scrollbar will go to the bottom position every time the new message arrives...

**here is my code.**

```
   <div class="scrollbar" id="style-2" id="scrollBar">
       <div id="conversation">
       </div>                 
    </div>

<script>
 function loadConversation(){
    $.get("get-conversation.php?to_hash=00000", function(data, status){
    document.getElementById("conversation").innerHTML = data;

    ///Scrolling to bottom
    var container_height = $( "#contain" ).height();
    $( "div.scrollbar" ).scrollTop( container_height+1000000000000 );


});

setTimeout(loadConversation,200);       
}
loadConversation();`
```

Please, help me. It is very important to me... I'd appreciate it greatly.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit crude. It keeps the timer going but only stops scrolling the to the bottom when the user is scrolling and continues when the user stops scrolling.

```
var isScrolling = false;

$(window).scroll(function() {
    isUserScrolling = true;
    clearTimeout($.data(this, 'scrollTimer'));
    $.data(this, 'scrollTimer', setTimeout(function() {
        // do something
        isUserScrolling = false;
    }, 250));
});

 function loadConversation(){
     if(!isUserScrolling){
        $.get("get-conversation.php?to_hash=00000", function(data, status){
           document.getElementById("conversation").innerHTML = data;

           ///Scrolling to bottom
           var container_height = $( "#contain" ).height();
            $( "div.scrollbar" ).scrollTop( container_height+1000000000000 );


       });
    }
    setTimeout(loadConversation,200);       
}
loadConversation();`
```

Comment: I don't know your code. This is conceptual. You are going to have to try the idea and console log each step.